# Turn off alphabetical sorting in swagger-codegen html

Tags: html, swagger, swagger-codegen

I'm using swagger-codgen -l html2 to generate my HTML API doc. It sorts the paths in alphabetical order. Is there any way to turn this off? I'd like to preserve the order in the .yaml file.